# KDE menu draw/redraw issue

Tags: kubuntu, kde

occasionally a drop down menu from an application (I think steam in particular) sort of bugs out and leaves me stuck with a frame that draws over everything...I've tried restarting kde/kwin [killall, kstart5, etc through research in other questions]. Regardless, it stays drawn in as if its a window until reboot. I do have some menu translucency options enabled in settings.  Once the bug occurs, the frame stays drawn over other applications and I'm able to drag windows under it while it remains drawn above obscuring visibility.  I don't have kvantum installed in this particular instance so I'm just running the most recent kde with nearly stock options available to me for configuration.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWmS9.jpg)

Comment: You hit the nail on the head; it's a bug, not a feature, so report it as a bug at https://bugs.kde.org/

Comment: @K7AAY Right on, thanks...wasn't sure if anyone else had experienced a similar issue or knew of a workaround.

Comment: If someone else had, they'd get pointed at http://bugs.kde.org but you can search for other KDE screen issues by clicking in the search box above the top red stripe; look for grey letters "Search on Ask Ubuntu" to the left of a spyglass icon

Comment: @K7AAY https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=412614 Just curious if this looks like a sufficient bug report...been using linux off and on for a long time but I've never interacted with the community much at all...

Comment: Good stuff; they will let you know how it could be perfected.